# how can i fix the import error in subgit ( layout option conflict )

Tags: import, subgit

i have tried to migrate an svn, but get the following error on import:

```
error: The following layout options conflict (intersect) in configuration file <File>
error:  svn.tags = tags/0.8.1/tags/*/js:refs/tags/0.8.1/*
error:  svn.tags = tags/0.8.1/*/js:refs/tags/0.8.1/*.
error: Please specify non-conflicting options and try again.
```

Where is the conflict here??

Answer (score 0):

The conflict is on the Git side of the mapping, you're trying to use the same git namespace to store the tags from different svn locations. Try to use different namespaces, like:

```
[svn]
    tags = tags/0.8.1/tags/*/js:refs/tags/0.8.1/tags/*
    tags = tags/0.8.1/*/js:refs/tags/0.8.1/*
```

this should work fine.